# append only one div out of others inside parent

Tags: jquery

I want to append only single div out of same id(not all)
and if different id is there like "b" then it will be append.
Thanks in Advance if anyone helps

```
$(document).ready function(e){
  var x = "<div>\
    <div id="a"></div>\
    <div id="a"></div>\
    <div id="a"></div>\
    <div id="b"></div>\
  </div>";
$('#parent').append(x);
});

<div id="parent"></div>
```

Comment: ids should be unique and you haven't escaped your quotes

Comment: i know but if this case will arise then how to solve. I know id is Unique

Comment: This may be of help - not sure it would work on ids though. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check with this Code It might be help you.

```
    $(document).ready (function(e){
    var x = "<div><div id='a'>a0</div><div id='a'>a1</div><div
        id='a'>a2</div><div id='b'>b1</div><div id='b'>b1</div><div   
           id='c'>c1</div><div id='b'>b2</div></div>";
    $('#parent').append(x);
    $('#parent').find("div").each(function ()
    {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var length = $('#parent').find("div#" + id).length;
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {   
            if (i > 0)
            {
                $('#parent').find("div#" + id+":eq("+i+")").remove();
            }
        }
    });
  });
```